# Array formula with MATCH gives no result when source table has only one row

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula

The following array formula results in #N/A when the source table has one row, but will result in 1 (which is OK) when the table has more than 1 row (even if there are two rows of which one is empty).

As a workaround, I added (in the Power Query query) an empty row to the table concerned (tblRCGRouteMasterCoProduct).

How to solve this?

```
=MATCH(1;(tblRCGRouteMasterCoProduct[RoutingCropGroupCode]="BEA") * (tblRCGRouteMasterCoProduct[RouteName]= "Sample Cleaning (2)") * (tblRCGRouteMasterCoProduct[LineNumber]= 10);0)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**NOTE**: In my formulas below, don't forget to change the commas `,` to semicolons `;` for your locale.

The problem seems to be that the second argument of the `MATCH` function needs to be an array.  For example:

```
`=MATCH(1,1,0) --> #N/A
```

but

```
=MATCH(1,{1},0) --> 1
```

So one way around it would be to use a different formula for a one-row data body range.

```
=IF(ROWS(tblRCGRouteMasterCoProduct[#Data])=1,IFERROR(1/(tblRCGRouteMasterCoProduct[RoutingCropGroupCode]="BEA") * (tblRCGRouteMasterCoProduct[RouteName]= "Sample Cleaning (2)") * (tblRCGRouteMasterCoProduct[LineNumber]= 10),NA()),MATCH(1,(tblRCGRouteMasterCoProduct[RoutingCropGroupCode]="BEA") * (tblRCGRouteMasterCoProduct[RouteName]= "Sample Cleaning (2)") * (tblRCGRouteMasterCoProduct[LineNumber]= 10),0))
```

Another method would be to ensure that even a single cell will be an array.  As pointed out by @JvdV, this can be done in the simplified fashion with

```
=MATCH(1,INDEX(1,),0)
```

which, for your formula, would be:

```
=MATCH(1,INDEX((tblRCGRouteMasterCoProduct[RoutingCropGroupCode]="BEA") * (tblRCGRouteMasterCoProduct[RouteName]= "Sample Cleaning (2)") * (tblRCGRouteMasterCoProduct[LineNumber]= 10),0),0)
```

Comment: We can create an array from `=MATCH(1,1,0)` using `=MATCH(1,INDEX(1;),0)`. Which means `=MATCH(1;INDEX((tblRCGRouteMasterCoProduct[RoutingCropGroupCode]="BEA") * (tblRCGRouteMasterCoProduct[RouteName]= "Sample Cleaning (2)") * (tblRCGRouteMasterCoProduct[LineNumber]= 10);0);0)` should work for OP. Plusside, no need to enter as CSE.

Comment: @JvdV Excellent. You should post that as an answer.

Comment: Please feel free to add, as I don't want to feel like robbing your initial observation. :).

Comment: @JvdV Tks.  Will do with attribution

Comment: @RonRosenfeld: Great! I succesfully applied your proposed solution, including what was proposed by JvdV.

Comment: Small correction to the proposed formula:     =MATCH(1,INDEX((tblRCGRouteMasterCoProduct[RoutingCropGroupCode]="BEA") * (tblRCGRouteMasterCoProduct[RouteName]= "Sample Cleaning (2)") * (tblRCGRouteMasterCoProduct[LineNumber]= 10),0,0),0)

Comment: @J.Vos If there is only a single dimension in the created array, the `column_num` argument is supposed to be optional.